# Ajax siempre me da error

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

Estoy aprendiendo hacer apps híbridas con (cordova) pero tengo un problema con ajax. Siempre me da error y creo que esta "correcto". El estado del archivo insert en el navegador siempre es OK(200) pero no hace el insert en la base de datos.

en mi razi (/) tengo index.html e insert.php y en /js/ajax.js e intentado imprimir el error desde ajax pero no imprime nada y tanpoco Apache me muestra error alguno. En cordova peor ni siquiera encuentra el archivo insert.php apesar de tenerlo en raiz y estar puesto.

este es la URL https://phonegapudemy2019.000webhostapp.com/

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

CRUD para MySQL

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark"></nav>
<div class="container">
    <h6 class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        Libros
    </h6>
    <form action="">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="autor">Autor</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="autor" name="autor">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="precio">Precio</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="precio" name="precio">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="insert" name="insert">Guardar</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/ajax.js"></script>
<script src="js/crud.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

insert.php

```
<?php 
include "conexion.php"; 
if(isset($_POST['insert'])){
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre']; 
    $autor = $_POST['autor']; 
    $precio = $_POST['precio']; 


    echo $nombre . $autor.$precio;    

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `libro` (`id`, `nombre`, `autor`, `precio`) VALUES (NULL, '$nombre', '$autor', '$precio')";
    $ejecutar = $conexion->query($sql); 

    if($ejecutar){
        echo "Correcto";  
    }else{
        echo "Error";
    }
}
```

?>

ajax.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#insert").click(function(){
    var nombre = $('#nombre').val(); 
    var autor = $('#autor').val(); 
    var precio =$('#precio').val(); 
    var datos = "nombre=" + nombre + "&autor=" + autor + "&precio=" + precio; 
    if($.trim(nombre).length > 0 & $.trim(autor).length > 0 & $.trim(precio).length>0){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/../insert.php",
            data: datos,
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                    console.log(xhr.responseText);
            },
            success:function(data){
                console.log(datos);
                console.log(data);
                if(data == "Correcto"){
                    alert("Guardado Correctamente");
                }
                else{
                    alert("Error");
                }
            }

        });
    }else{
        alert("Complete los datos");
    }
});
```

});

Comment: `$sql = "INSERT INTO `libro` (`id`, `nombre`, `autor`, `precio`) VALUES (NULL, '$nombre', '$autor', '$precio')";`, no puedes mandar `null` como parámetro, si activaste el autoincrementar, pueder quitar el ` id ` de tu `insert`,

Comment: `$sql = "INSERT INTO `libro` (`nombre`, `autor`, `precio`) VALUES ('$nombre', '$autor', '$precio')";` de esta manera también me da error.

Comment: `$row_cnt = $ejecutar ->num_rows;`  y `echo($row_cnt)`

Answer (score 0):

Trata esto:

```
<?php 
include "conexion.php"; 
if(isset($_POST['insert'])){
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre']; 
    $autor = $_POST['autor']; 
    $precio = $_POST['precio']; 


    #echo $nombre . $autor.$precio;    

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `libro` (`id`, `nombre`, `autor`, `precio`) VALUES (NULL, '$nombre', '$autor', '$precio')";
    $ejecutar = $conexion->query($sql); 

    if($ejecutar){
        echo "Correcto";  
    }else{
        echo "Error";
    }
}
?>
```

Trata de comentar este echo,

```
echo $nombre . $autor.$precio;
```

Ya que recuerda que tu `success:function` solo esta esperando un echo no dos.

espero que te funcione un saludo.